# Was Sidious damaged other than his face?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, revenge-of-the-sith

In episode 3 it is shown that Palpatine is damaged when fighting Windu. However, it only appears to have affected his face and caused him to look disfigured.

[image: Palpatine face]

Was there any other damage to him because of the fight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. At the very minimum we know that his hands and wrists were also disfigured.

[image]